# What is an L-Function and how can it be used for categorization?

Tags: category-theory, modular-forms, l-functions

On hackernews, I came across [this article](http://aimath.org/aimnews/lmfdb/), describing the  LMFDB,

> the database of L-functions, modular forms, and related objects

which aims at the categorization of mathematical objects where L-functions play the role of DNA.

I'm asking from a philosophical perspective, as the scope of this categorization seems enormous and intriguing ("periodic table..."). I know an L-function is a function on the complex plane, with poles, like the zeta-function. So I assume categorizations works via the distribution of these poles - but how exactly does this work here? What is it in basic terms (english, data-structure, algorithm...)?

Comment: "with poles, like the zeta-function" - not necessarily; some of the Dirichlet $L$-functions are holomorphic.

Comment: I can't really answer the question, but just so you don't get too excited, it's certainly not a periodic table for all mathematical objects, whatever that would mean. But I do hear that these things show up surprisingly widely.